# Fixing Table of Contents in Memoir Class

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I have a document of class memoir. These are all my settings:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside, 11pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{palatino}
\setlength{\parindent}{2.5em}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,  tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

However, my table of contents is not as I would like. I have chapters like this:

```
\chapter*{Abstract}
\input{chapters/abstract} \cite{dirac}

\chapter*{Dedication}
To...

\chapter*{Declaration}
I declare that..

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I want to thank...

\tableofcontents
\input{chapters} 

\chapter*{Introduction}
\input{chapters/intro}

\chapter*{Methods}
\input{chapters/chapter02}

\chapter*{Results}
\input{chapters/chapter03}
```

When I print table of contents however, I only get:

```
CONTENTS 

Contents                      5
Bibliography                  61
```

I would like to have all the different chapters listed, as well as an index of tables and figures used. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't post such fragments only, please! Use `\chapter{...}` not `\chapter*{...}` -- You most likely want numbered chapters, not unnumbered ones. For the `Declaration` other things have to be done, e.g. `\frontmatter`

Comment: Why are you using `chapter*`? Starred document dividers does not reach the toc

Comment: Welcome, remove all asterisks from the chapters and use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`.

Comment: Free ebook for begginers: [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

If some parts of the `\chapter` -like entries should be unnumbered but still appear in the `ToC`, either use `\frontmatter` and switch later on to `\mainmatter` where appropiate or say `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` as Johannes suggested.

This approach is not restricted to `memoir` by the way -- any `class` that supports `\frontmatter` etc. will behave like this. (The counter method should work always, anyway!)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside, 11pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{palatino}
\setlength{\parindent}{2.5em}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,  tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*

\frontmatter

\chapter{Abstract}

\chapter{Dedication}
To...

\chapter{Declaration}
I declare that..

\chapter{Acknowledgements}
I want to thank...

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Methods}

\chapter{Results}

\end{document}
```

[image]