# Changing Chapter Titles in Memoir Class

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am using the memoir document class, with chapters. However, I would like to remove the Chapter title from each, so it doesn't say "Chapter 1" and then "Introduction" underneath. I just want it to say "Introduction." Yet, when I remove Chapter titles by using * , I cannot call then in the Table of Contents. So, I am wondering how to change the Chapter titles, or if there is another way to solve this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside, 11pt, openany]{memoir}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/intro}

\chapter{Methods}
\input{chapters/chapter02}
```

Comment: Add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` to the preamble to have all chapters unnumbered. or have a look at that question from yesterday: [Fixing Table of Contents in Memoir Class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326846)

Comment: @Johannes_B memoir has an easier interface `\setsecnumdepth{none} ` to turn of numbering completely. To the OP: why don't you want the introduction numbered if it is part of the mainmatter. If it just listing what you are doing in this doc, then also use `\frontmatter ` and move the introduction up before `\mainmatter `. Btw: that `secnumdepth `  you are doing is being reset by `\mainmatter `, look up `\setsecnumdepth` and `\maxsecnumdepth` in the memoir manual

Comment: @daleif Do you want to add an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In memoir frontmatter disables sec numbering. `\mainmatter` re-enable it, but frontmatter does **not** store the current value and restores it. Rather is restores to a user defined value.

So in memoir the proper method is:

```
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection} 
\setmaxsecnumdepth{subsubsection} % mainmatter restore to this
```

There is a similar command (`\settocdepth`) to set the depth of the toc. Its max version is hardly ever needed (I've never used it)