# Double Chapter Headers with Memoir package

Tags: chapters, memoir, section-titles

I'm working on type setting a chaptered text, using the memoir package. I'm getting two chapter headings when I use the `/chapter{chapter title goes here}` command. It's a pretty plain layout, and I'm very confused where the extra heading is coming from!

I want to keep the large, dropped header, but I would not like to keep the top, smaller header.

[image: screenshot of generated pdf's chapter header]

See example: `sandbox01.tex` @ https://www.overleaf.com/read/nxvwxfqqwccq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the easiest way (when using memoir) in a different question -- [Changing Chapter Titles in Memoir Class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326908/changing-chapter-titles-in-memoir-class#comment799992_326908)

`\setsecnumdepth{none}`

Answer (score 0):

You say to do one thing here:

```
\chapter{chapter title goes here}
```

But do another in Overleaf (that is wrong):

```
\chapter{Chapter One}
```

The  first, with  `dowding` chapter style will produce:

> *<sub>Chapter One</sub>*
> ***chapter title goes here***

But obviously `\chapter{Chapter One}` will be typed as:

> *<sub>Chapter One</sub>*
> ***Chapter One***

If you move that command after `\chapter{Chapter Three}` you will note that the output will change now to:

> *<sub>Chapter Four</sub>*
> ***Chapter One***

That is, first "Chapter" + "Number" is a prefix typed automatically. The command argument is not to type you again, maybe with the wrong number,  but to provide a meaningful title as "[Foo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar)", so  `\chapter{Foo}` will produce:

> *<sub>Chapter Correct Number</sub>*
> ***Foo***

If you only want really  just "Chapter One", there are some alternatives, from worst to best:

```
\chapter{}
```

This show only the small chapter prefix in text, but nothing in ToC and header in following pages, unless you add an optional argument:

```
\chapter[Chapter One]{}
```

But moreover, the empty mandatory argument could produce problems with some chapter styles as `ger`, so is not a good idea at all.

Better:

```
\chapter*{Chapter One}
```

This will show the title just once, but it will not appear in ToC, unless you add it manually with:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter One}
```

But still will be omitted in the default header, so the best is:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} % in the preamble
\chapter[A][B]{C}
```

Where "A" should be the chapter title in ToC, "B" the  chapter title in the header, and C the chapter title in the main text. e.g.:

```
\chapter[The chapter one][Ch. One]{Chapter One}
```